# How to call Api using alaram manager on a specific time when android app not runing

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

i am working on an  application where we accept auction bid we have auction 
  start and end time in between this time we collect bids from buyer .
   after auction end i want to call an api automatically where server know that auction end and server send highest bid notification to seller

Comment: use alarm manager in its reciever send api

Comment: can u explain how can i use @NehaRathore thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be notified when the auction time ends so you can make a call to the server. If that's the case, you can register a broadcast receiver to receive the broadcast intent and then you can decide to use the JobScheduler or workManger to make a call to the server in the background.

here's a code lab link on broadcast receivers (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-broadcast-receivers/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#0)

for jobScheduler (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-job-scheduler/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#0)

hope this helps.